# Is the average of the product of two operator zero, if their individual averages vanish?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, mathematics

Given two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ such that $\langle \hat{A} \rangle = \langle \hat{B} \rangle = 0$, then what can we say about $\langle \hat{A} \hat{B}\rangle$? In particular is $\langle \hat{A} \hat{B}\rangle =0$? Here $\langle \rangle$ denotes the average with respect to some state?

Comment: Unfortunately the product of averages isn't directly equal to the average of products unless the covariance of the operators is null. Perhaps someone can be more explicit so you can see the proof.

Answer (score 10):

In $\mathbb{C}^2$, take $A=B= \mathrm{diag}(-1,1)$ and $|\psi\rangle= (1,1)^t$ up to normalisation. It holds $\langle A\rangle=\langle B\rangle=0$, but $\langle AB\rangle \neq 0$.

Answer (score 8):

No, when the expectation values $\langle\hat{A}\rangle$ and
$\langle\hat{B}\rangle$ are zero, then the expectation value
$\langle \hat{A} \hat{B}\rangle$ is not necessarily zero.

Here is a simple counter-example.
Consider a state described by this symmetric wavefunction:

[image: wavefunction]

Obviously for this state the expectation value of operator $\hat{x}$ is zero,
because values $-x$ and $+x$ occur with the same probability.
$$\langle\hat{x}\rangle = 0$$

But the expection value of operator $\hat{x}^2$ is positive,
because $x^2$ is  always positive.
$$\langle\hat{x}^2\rangle > 0$$

Comment: Very intuitive answer +1!